# jQuery-shake-on-clik on div - shakes no matter where i click

Tags: jquery, html, shake

I'm trying to make a `<div>` shake when the div ITSELF is clicked, but so far, the said `<div>` shakes no matter where I click on the page.

Here's my code:

```css
#port-two {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  resize: vertical;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px !important;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 200 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).click(function() {
    $("#port-two").effect("shake");
  });
</script>

<div id="port-two" class="me">this is what's supposed to shake WHEN IT ITSELF IS CLICKED. It now shakes no matter where you click :(</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply because you attached the event handler to the `document`. To do what you require you should attach it to the `#port-two` element. Try this:

```css
#port-two {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  resize: vertical;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px !important;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 200 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#port-two').click(function() {
      $(this).effect("shake");
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="port-two" class="me">It now shakes only when clicked :)</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! I'm a total rookie following the program over at FreeCodeCamp. I've been wrestling with this bit for an hour or two now. I read somewhere the document-attachment was something I needed to do, but I can't remember why anymore. Guess I better check the documentation again.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. With regards to the document, you need to run your code when the document is ready - that's what `$(function() { });` is doing in my code above. When you attach events they should be placed on the element which is going to raise that element (or a parent if the event bubbles up the DOM)

Answer (score 1):

You have added the click event to "document" instead of your element.
I would also recommend that you encapsulate anything which is related
to the DOM with $(document).ready...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#port-two" ).click(function() {
        $(this).effect( "shake" );
    });
});
```